# How to validate forms in JS when the form name changes dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I have a profile page in php for students of a school.

Each single profile page loops over the mysql database to get each course that the student is enrolled in. It can be several courses.

For each course there is a small form that allows me to fill a specific field to put the final grade by hand for each course.

My problem is that I want to target each form in javascript in order to validate that when I click "submit" the field is not empty.

It does work (in the sense that it does the validation), but it targets the first form, because I'm using the form's name, which is the same for every course.

### This is my form:

```
<form class="form-inline" name="formEmisionCertificado" action="/certificados/emitirCertificado.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="fechaFinalizacionTexto" id="fechaFinalizacionTexto">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">emitir certificado</button>   
</form>
```

### And here is my validation:

```
$("form[name='formEmisionCertificado']").validate({
    errorClass:'alert alert-danger',
    rules: {
              fechaFinalizacionTexto: {
                required: true
              }
            },
    messages:{
              fechaFinalizacionTexto: {
                required: "Falta la fecha de aprobación del curso"
              }                  
    }
  });
```

My problem is that every form is going to be called "formEmisionCertificado", so I thought to attach to every form name the course id in PHP, so every form name is like "*formEmisionCertificado23*", "*formEmisionCertificado95*", "*formEmisionCertificado112*" and so on.

I know very little of JS, how may I target each form when the names are different? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Validation like this should be done with PHP on the server rather than client side as it is more secure.

Comment: I know but this is an admin form, and it's just to prevent to accidentally submit the empty form and have to wait for the server's response...